# Unable to open a file stored in adls using python with command

Tags: python, apache-spark

There is a file stored in adls. I am able read the file using spark.

```
display(spark.read.format('csv').load("abfss://TIMESTAMP.txt"))
```

But when I trying to open the file with below commands it says no such file or directory.

```
with open("abfss://TIMESTAMP.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.read()
print(lines)
```

It says "No such file or directory"

Comment: Does this help? with open("TIMESTAMP.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.read()
print(lines)

Comment: It says 'No such file or directory'. How will the command know which path to look for in adls?

Comment: Does this help abfs://? Just one 's'

Comment: It doesn't work as well, I guess python 'with open' command is not able to understand the adls path